# Why is the user's session seems to vanish sometimes?

Tags: php, session-variables

I recently changed my server to host my website/smartphone application. Since then, some users seems to have their $_SESSION "crashing" more or less randomly ; in other words they got disconnected or datas stored in $_SESSION are all lost in once.

I'm checking `php.ini` to see if it could come from it, all differences I can see are those ones :

```
session.gc_probability : Old Server 0 | New Server 1
sesssion.gc_maxlifetime : Old Server 3600 | New Server 1440
```

Does the problem come from `session.gc_probability` set to 1 in the new server ? From what I understand, it calculates probability to flush the $_SESSION everytime session is initialised, does this seem everytime that `session_start()` is called ?

Thank your for your help.

(Of course the php code itself didn't change from the old to the new server, so it can't come from it...)

Comment: It can either be that your session cookies expire, and PHP has no ways of retrieving the session from the storage, or plain and simply your session variables expires. You should not be storing any information in the $_SESSION that you can not rebuild either with or without some user input.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai Sorry I don't speak english very well so I'm not sure to understand what you mean by your last sentence ?

Comment: @Vae Do you have other PHP scripts on your server which uses sessions? Do you change the session settings in these PHP scripts? Does the server use different session settings for different PHP script or directories?

Comment: @Vae Keep in mind that 1440 seconds, which are 24 minutes. After that time of inactivity, the session might get deleted by the server (depending on the server configuration and probability).

Comment: @Progman The $_SESSIONS are used all along the user's navigation, to store and get his choices about what to display or not for example. So $_SESSIONS are permanently used. And the strange fact is that they seems to be deleted even if the user has a recent activity (< 1440s).
But I'm gonna ask the server holder to change gc_probability and gc_maxlifetime as it was on the previous server, all I can see is that for now...